# PDFBOX Flatten Acro-form causes displaced text from original location

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-form

I used PDFBOX to fill form and then flatten it using api. Resulting PDF is not correctly displayed

[Link TO PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EbCyWET5vsDBEixGi3PBQpoKj3ws6XHI/view?usp=sharing)

I used PDFBox 2.0.21

sample code to flatten form

```
    val sourceDocument = getTemplate(templatePath)
    val form = sourceDocument.documentCatalog.acroForm
    fillHeader(form, headerParam, currentPage, totalPages, it)
    fillData(form, it, currentPage)
    form.flatten(form.fieldTree.toList(),false)
```

full code is posted at [Full code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822533/pdfbox-acroform-filled-but-when-opened-in-acrobat-reader-values-disappears)

I am not sure if this problem is PDFBox or Adobe

Need help

Comment: It works for me with 2.0.22 but I only tested with one field. You should retest with 2.0.22 because there were bug fixes related to flattening, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4958

Comment: I used the SetField.java example fron the source code download and added `pdf.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().flatten();`. And for me the filled field had a black, not a blue font.

Comment: What worked - updating to 2.0.22 ?

Comment: Updating version to 2.0.22 worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to version 2.0.22 fixes this problem with flattening, which was described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4958). Version 2.0.22 was released at the end of 2020.

Always use the latest version, use the [maven versions plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to detect the existence of new versions.